# how do pause this loop for a fixed time frame?

Tags: php

I do have a array which will read text file and do api call and then insert these result to mySQL. but when it run in bulk the response from API server is slow and due to this many of the results are coming blank. what I am looking is is there a way to pause this loop for each call say 5 seconds to get result from api server so it wont get blank results.

this code is below

```
//connect to your database 
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "password"); 
mysql_select_db("somedb"); 

//read your text file into an array, one entry per line 
$lines = file('filename.txt'); 

//loop through each website URL  
foreach ($lines as $website_url) { 

    //make the request to the compete API 
    $response = file_get_contents("http://apps.compete.com/sites/" . $website_url . "/trended/rank/?apikey=0sdf456sdf12sdf1"); 

    //decode the request 
    $response = json_decode($request); 

    //get the rank from the response 
    $rank = $response['something'];  

    //insert the website URL and its rank 
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO website_ranks (website_url, rank) VALUES ('" . mysql_real_escape_string($website_Url) . "', " . $rank . ")"); 

}
```

Comment: @Femaref You are incorrect, it is in seconds.

Comment: @Femaref sleep(2) is taken in seconds, usleep(2000000) is taken in microseconds [sleep(2) == usleep(2000000)]

Comment: Based on the way the question is worded, it sounds as if he thinks file_get_contents isn't blocking (which it is).  Just throwing that out there in case. sleep() at the end of the loop should be sufficient otherwise.  @Femaref, sleep()'s argument needs to be in seconds, not ms.

Comment: where should i put?? after the API call??

Comment: @mathew as long as it's in the foreach loop it doesn't really matter, each loop will still take ~5 seconds no matter where the sleep call is

Answer (score 4):

Use the sleep command

```
 sleep (5);
```

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't it make more sense to verify the server responded rather than sleeping for an arbitrary amount of time?

Answer (score 0):

One alternate approach I'd recommend using instead of looping with a single INSERT statement is using a BULK INSERT syntax with your RDBMS provider. This will speed up the process considerably.

That syntax usually looks like this:

INSERT INTO tablename(col1, col2) VALUES (...)